# Why do we need self when refer method with @staticmethod decorator in python class?

Tags: python, static

I don't understand why we need to use `self` when we refer to the method with `@staticmethod` decorator.

For example, the `self.circle_area` method in `area` method.

```py
class Pizza:
    def __init__(self, radius, ingredients):
        self.radius = radius
        self.ingredients = ingredients

    def area(self):
        return self.circle_area(self.radius)

    @staticmethod
    def circle_area(r):
        return r ** 2 * math.pi
```

Comment: You don't need it, it could also be written as `Pizza.circle_area(self.radius)`. Using `self` can sometimes be more convenient because you'll have one less thing to worry about if you ever rename the `Pizza` class.

Comment: If you call circle_area method from Pizza Class itself but not initiate the instance. You don't even need the @staticmethod decorator.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `circle_area()` without `self`, your Python interpreter will try to find the name of the method with the global scope. But the method `circle_area` is defined in the class `Pizza`, which is not visible with the global scope, so the interpreter can't access it. By adding `self` to your method call, you can specify where the method you want to call is located.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. @laviande22

Answer (score 0):

You don't. `self` and `Pizza` refer to the exact same thing (you could do `self.circle_area(self.radius)`). However, `self` is more often used by convention.

If you call `surface_area()` without `self` or `pizza`, then you will get an error because `surface_area()` is not defined in the global scope.